# Split row into multiple rows based on various columns

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe has the following structure

```
x   Total   PartA   PartB
0   13      6       7
1   19      8       11
...
```

Now i would like to transform the dataframe into

```
x     Val     Colname
0     13      "Total"
0     6       "PartA"
0     7       "PartB"
1     19      "Total"
1     8       "PartA"
1     11      "PartB"
```

Hence, i want to transform every row into a row for each of the "Total", "PartA" and "PartB" columns. I've been searching for an elegant dplyr solution but my lack of terminology makes it hard to find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tidyr` we can use `gather`. Additionally, we can use `dplyr` to `arrange` `x` and `select` the columns in a specific order, this will make the data look just like the example you've provided:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(key = "ColName", value = "Val", -x) %>% 
  arrange(x) %>% 
  select(x, Val, ColName)
```

> ```
>   x Val ColName
> 1 0  13   Total
> 2 0   6   PartA
> 3 0   7   PartB
> 4 1  19   Total
> 5 1   8   PartA
> 6 1  11   PartB
> ```

---

Data:

```
Lines = "x   Total   PartA   PartB
         0   13      6       7
         1   19      8       11"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```

Comment: I knew that some function like that had to exist! Thanks! :-)

Comment: No problem! Happy to help